# How to track events on a flash button with the new Asynchronous Code

Tags: flash, events, asynchronous, event-handling, google-analytics

This may be a very basic question but I cannot work it out now. I have a 'flash banner' on my site for which once clicked on you go to another page on the site. I want to track this click as an event. HTML event tracking works fine. Previously the code I used was:

on (press) {
    getURL("javascript:pageTracker._trackEvent('Banner', 'Banner
Click','Banner1');");
}

on (release) {
    getURL("http://www.e2save.com/content/mobile-phone-sale");
}

Now that I have changed the code to the Google Analytics Asynchronous it does not track even through I have update it with new _gag.push code.

Can anybody answer or help me on this.

Many thanks

Jk

Comment: Did you also update the global code on your actual page to be async code? _gaq.push in your onpress will only work if the global code is also async style.  Also, post what you actually updated the on(press) code to be.

Comment: Yes the global code was updated. Here is what I then changed it to:  
on (release) {
    getURL("_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Banner', 'Banner Click', 'Banner1']);");
}

on (release) {
    getURL("http://www.e2save.com");
}       - Im a designer and not part of the web team so excuse my lack of coding knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

This question was on google support foum. Have you try the solution they found there?

```
onPress = function() {
   ExternalInterface.call("_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'ENTER STRING TO REPORT TO G.A.'])");
}
```

Maybe you could find this [topic](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=47183d0c1466e278&hl=en&fid=47183d0c1466e27800048bd1cc12a805&hltp=2) helpful.

Comment: Yes the global code was replaced on the site. But for all my searching I cannot find support to answer the simple URL call to track as a event. I will try this method from the answer below and report back. Im assuming I change the trckPageview to trackEvent